# Pytorch grid_sample for image volumes and landmarks

Tags: python, pytorch, registration

I want to use the pytorch grid_sample to calculate the total registration error. I have a volume of shape (Batch, Channel,H,W,D) and landmarks of shape (Batch, Num_lms, 3). In the first step i want to calculate the warped landmarks using a exemplary displacement field, but i cant make the dimensions work. I tried:

```
dispf = torch.ones_like(torch.tensor(img)).unsqueeze(0)
dispf = torch.unsqueeze(dispf.expand(3,*ddf.shape[1:]),0)
warped_lms = torch.nn.functional.grid_sample(dispf, fixed_landmarks.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0))
```

`RuntimeError: grid_sampler(): expected grid to have size 2 in last dimension, but got grid with sizes [1, 1, 1, Num_lms, 3]`

does anyone have an idea? Afterwards I want to compare the output with the moved_lms (Batch, Num_lms, 3)